# Flutter: Do FutureBuilder Loads everything at the same time?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

My app has a book summaries Feature, Now since I don't have money to host an API, I am using `Firebase/Firestore` database where I add summaries manually and then retrieve data from firebase to App.

I am using `FutureBuilder` for it.
Now say I have 10 summaries will `FutureBuilder` first load all 10 of them and then display data on screen(which is a `ListView.builder` and can show only 2 summaries without scrolling) or it will load only the data which need to be painted on the screen just like simple `ListView.builder`.

```
// code to retrieve data:

Future<QuerySnapshot> getFeedsfromFb() async {
  var data = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('feedItem')
      .orderBy('feedId', descending: true).getDocuments();
  return data;
}

// building widget:

Widget feed() {
  return Container(
    width: deviceWidth,
    height: deviceHeight / 3,
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getFeedsfromFb(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length > 10
                  ? 10
                  : snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  width: deviceWidth / 2.5,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => FeedIntro(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]['feedId'])));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          // width: 150,
                          height: 150,
                          foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                    snapshot.data.documents[index]['feedImage'],
                                  ),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']),
                        )),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Sorry Something went wrong!'));
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
              ),
            );
          }
        }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FutureBuilder` will load all items at the same, but only needed data by `ListView.builder` will be painted on the screen.

Comment: does this means say I have a lot of data may be 100 summaries then it will take a lot of time to fetch data? I didn't want the fetching time to be more than 5 secs on good internet connection.

Comment: Yes ! if you want the loading time to be small even on the worst connection you should load data as parts when needed. Say at the first time load 20 summaries, and when the user reaches end of scroll load more item (more 20). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323286/how-to-do-pagination-in-gridview-flutter/56323552#56323552