# How can I Pagination In GridView.builder Flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, pagination

I have successfully get `users` by category but now I want to do `Pagination`. How can I do this. Kindly help me with the `code`. Thanks

> API for get users

```
static String baseUrl = "http://newprotectco.com/hello/api/";

static Future<http.Response> getUsers(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + "Users/index").replace(queryParameters: params ?? {});
    var response = await http.get(uri);
    return response;
  }
```

> Here I'm getting user in Gridview

```
class UsersCategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  List<Data> list=[];
   UsersCategoryPage(this.list,{Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UsersCategoryPage> createState() => _UsersCategoryPageState();
}

class _UsersCategoryPageState extends State<UsersCategoryPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<UsersCategoryPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: Dimensions.width10, vertical: Dimensions.height10),
        child: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.list.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: Dimensions.aspectRatio,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: Dimensions.height15),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width5),
                  child: WorkersList(
                    usersDetail: widget.list[index],
                    press: () => pushNewScreen(context,
                        screen: ContactUser(usersDetail: widget.list[index])),
                  ),
                )),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

> **Update**

```
class _UsersCategoryPageState extends State<UsersCategoryPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<UsersCategoryPage> {
  int perTime = 10;
  int length = widget.list.length < perTime ? widget.list.length : perTime;
  bool loading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    super.build(context);
    return LazyLoadScrollView(
      onEndOfPage: () async{
       setState(() {
         loading = true;
       });
       await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
       (length + perTime) >= widget.list.length?setState(() {
         length = widget.list.length;
       }):setState(() {
         length = length + perTime;
       });
      },
      child: Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width10, vertical: Dimensions.height10),
          child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: length >= widget.list.length?widget.list.length:loading? length + 1: length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  childAspectRatio: Dimensions.aspectRatio, crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: Dimensions.height15),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => length >= widget.list.length ? index == widget.list.length
                  ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ) :Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width5),
                    child: WorkersList(
                      usersDetail: widget.list[index],
                      press: () => pushNewScreen(context, screen: ContactUser(usersDetail: widget.list[index])),
                    ),
                  )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I tried [how to do pagination in GridView (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323286/how-to-do-pagination-in-gridview-flutter) before without success.

Comment: I have some ideas, I will post the answer later

Comment: yes sure I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: I posted the answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to do pagination in GridView (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323286/how-to-do-pagination-in-gridview-flutter)

Comment: I've tried it but not succeeded.

Comment: @eamirho3ein bro can you help e on this?

Comment: does not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977510/10306997) answer help ?

Comment: No, that's why I came to you. Kindly help me on this

Comment: ohh wait a sec I'll try this now

Comment: No this is also not helping me

Comment: If you can help by code I'll be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

First, install a package called [`lazy_load_scrollview`](https://pub.dev/packages/lazy_load_scrollview). Then, try the following code:

```
int perTime = 10;
int length = widget.list.length < perTime ? widget.list.length : perTime;
bool loading = false;
```

---

```
LazyLoadScrollView(
  onEndOfPage: () async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    };

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

    (length + perTime) >= widget.list.length
        ? setState(() {
            length = widget.list.length;
          };
        : setState(() {
            length = length + perTime;
          };

    setState(() {
      loading = false;
    };
  },
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: length >= widget.list.length
        ? widget.list.length
        : loading
            ? length + 1
            : length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      childAspectRatio: Dimensions.aspectRatio,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: Dimensions.height15,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return length >= widget.list.length ? index == widget.list.length
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width5),
                  child: WorkersList(
                    usersDetail: widget.list[index],
                    press: () => pushNewScreen(context,
                        screen: ContactUser(usersDetail: widget.list[index])),
                  ),
                ) : index == length ? Center(
                                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            ) : Padding(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width5),
                                                  child: WorkersList(
                                                    usersDetail: widget.list[index],
                                                    press: () => pushNewScreen(context,
                                                        screen: ContactUser(usersDetail: widget.list[index])),
                                                  ),
                                                );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: bro this package is `19  months old`. will it be suitable?

Comment: I am using this

Comment: don't you have another way without any package?

Comment: I've also tried pagination before, this is my own approach, I've tried it in my app and it should be fine.

Comment: No, I have no other way

Comment: ok let me try it. i'll let you know

Comment: `int length = widget.list.length < perTime ? widget.list.length : perTime;` getting error on `widget`, `perTime`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer. (Documentation)  Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

Comment: But I see that `widget.list.length` is used in the code you shared in your question: `itemCount: widget.list.length,`

Comment: yes but it is giving error

Comment: You should put `perTime`, `length` and `loading` into `build`

Comment: Don't put them outside `build`

Comment: Expected an identifier. 
Expected to find ':'. end clause of `pading` and `GridView.builder`

Comment: what is `state` now?

Comment: Error on `state` Undefined name 'state'.

Comment: after running code I'm not seeing any changes

Comment: Sorry, it seems my code doesn't work for you, I don't think I can help you

Comment: by using this code I get 10 user per screen but know how to load others?

Comment: Just scroll down

Comment: nothing happen.

Comment: Sorry, it seems my code doesn't work for you, I don't think I can help you

Comment: onEndOfPage() { } is not triggering on scroll end.